# How to convert a thumbnail from Box android-content-sdk to a bitmap?

Tags: android, sdk, thumbnails, box

As seen in this issue there are two methods in Box android-content-sdk that return a request:
[How to get thumbnails with box android-content-sdk (notV2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32968067/how-to-get-thumbnails-with-box-android-content-sdk-notv2/33044593#33044593)

The target of the first is a local file and the other a OutputStram object.

In my case I would get a bitmap in a AsyncTask like this:

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(InputStream is)
```

So finding no solution with the Box android-sdk-content, I tried to convert the outputStream to InputStream like this:(This method is called in AsynckTask)

```
    protected Bitmap getThumbBox(final String id, final BoxApiFile apiFile) throws IOException {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        PipedInputStream in = new PipedInputStream();
        final PipedOutputStream out = new PipedOutputStream(in);

        new Thread(
                new Runnable(){
                    public void run(){
                        //put your code that writes data to the outputstream here.
                        BoxRequestsFile.DownloadThumbnail  downloadThumbnail = apiFile.getDownloadThumbnailRequest(out,id);
                    }
                }
        ).start();
        //data can be read from the pipedInputStream here.
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        return bitmap;
}
```

According with this: 
http://io-tools.sourceforge.net/easystream/outputstream_to_inputstream/Pipes.html

But with no success.
Any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I managed to get the thumbnail into a bitmap:

```
protected Bitmap getThumbBox(final String id, final BoxSession session)  {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        BoxDownload req = null;
        try {
            req = new BoxApiFile(session).getDownloadThumbnailRequest(bos, id).setMinSize(256).send();
        } catch (BoxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        byte[] byteArr = bos.toByteArray();
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArr, 0, byteArr.length);
        return bm;
    }
```